# program crashes when i add code to make a button turn off bluetooth

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

i added a button and i want to make it turn off bluetooth when i click it but when i install it in my phone to test it straight doesnt open,
this is all the code , i have no idea why its crashing

```
     OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                 Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
        button.Click += delegate
        {


            BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter.Disable();

        };
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: Call `SetContentView(...)` before you access any views in your activity.

Comment: thank you so much, i had no idea about that and i didnt find it anywhere , so thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Call SetContentView(...) before you access any views in your activity.

thank you alexanders916

Comment: Please do not forget to mark your answer after two days, it will help others who have simialr issue.